# SQL records only for 3 consecutive months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

I have table for emp. attendance sheet:

```
emp_No Absent_Date
-------------------
111     01/03/2012
111     05/05/2012
222     13/02/2012
222     01/03/2012
222     02/03/2012
222     29/04/2012
222     09/09/2012
333     15/05/2012
333     18/09/2012
333     19/09/2012
```

I need to return the rows like below:

```
emp_No Absent_Date
-------------------
222     13/02/2012
222     01/03/2012
222     02/03/2012
222     29/04/2012
```

because only emp no 222 having absent in 3 consecutive months.

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do is to group the absences by consecutive months.  Let me assume that you are using a reasonable database that supports the `dense_rank()` function and basic window functions.

The idea is to find months in sequence that have absences.  Then, count the number of months in each sequence for each employee and keep the ones that have more than three months.

The query does this by converting the month to a month number -- 12 times the year plus the month.  It then uses a simple observation.  The month number minus a sequence of numbers is a constant, for consecutive months.  Usually, I use `row_number()` for the sequence.  Because you have duplicate absences in a month, I'm using `dense_rank()`.

```
select emp_no, absent_date
from (select a.*,
             max(monthnum) over (partition by emp_no, groupnum) as lastmonth,
             min(monthnum) over (partition by emp_no, groupnum) as firstmonth
      from (select a.*,
                   monthnum - dense_rank() over (partition by emp_no order by monthnum) as groupnum
            from (select a.*,
                         year(a.absent_date)*12+month(a.absent_date) as monthnum
                  from Attendance a
                 ) a
           ) a
     ) a
where lastmonth - firstmonth >= 2
```

Finally, because you want the absent dates -- as opposed to just the employee numbers -- I find the first and last month using window functions and use their difference as a filter.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest is to do a self join of the table three times, each time adding 1 month to the date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S1.emp_No
FROM attendance_sheet S1
JOIN attendance_sheet S2
ON S1.emp_No = S2.emp_No
AND Month(S1.Absent_Date + 1 MONTH) = Month(S2.Absent_Date)
AND Year(S1.Absent_Date + 1 MONTH) = Year(S2.Absent_Date)
JOIN attendance_sheet S3
ON S2.emp_No = S3.emp_No
AND Month(S2.Absent_Date + 1 MONTH) = Month(S3.Absent_Date)
AND Year(S2.Absent_Date + 1 MONTH) = Year(S3.Absent_Date)
```

This will give you all the unique `emp_No`'s. Now to get the result you want, you'll have to do another join (respectively I'll use `IN` for easier reading):

```
SELECT * 
FROM attendance_sheet
WHERE emp_No IN (
  SELECT S1.emp_No
  FROM attendance_sheet S1
  JOIN attendance_sheet S2
  ON S1.emp_No = S2.emp_No
  AND Month(S1.Absent_Date + 1 MONTH) = Month(S2.Absent_Date)
  AND Year(S1.Absent_Date + 1 MONTH) = Year(S2.Absent_Date)
  JOIN attendance_sheet S3
  ON S2.emp_No = S3.emp_No
  AND Month(S2.Absent_Date + 1 MONTH) = Month(S3.Absent_Date)
  AND Year(S2.Absent_Date + 1 MONTH) = Year(S3.Absent_Date)
)
```

See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc8c6/3) to try (I had to change the month adding syntax from standard SQL to MySQL).

Comment: Thanks. But how to use this '+ 1 MONTH' here?

Comment: See the fiddle, I changed it there so it works with MySQL. If you're running another server, you'll have to adapt the syntax accordingly.

Comment: i use MS SQL. i have added 1 month with absent date. But its showing more records than actual.

Comment: If the result is OK for MySQL (see the fiddle) then I think you did something wrong with the date adding here.

Comment: Its working. Is there any way to return only records for 3 consecutive months? 222     13/02/2012  
222     01/03/2012    
222     02/03/2012  
222     29/04/2012

Answer (score 1):

Try for this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(
SELECT  E1.Attendance _No,
        E1.Absent_Date
FROM Attendance  E1
JOIN Attendance  E2
ON E2.Attendance _No = E1.Attendance _No
AND MONTH(E2.Absent_Date)  = MONTH(E1.Absent_Date) + 1
JOIN Attendance  E3
ON E3.Attendance _No = E2.Attendance _No
AND MONTH(E3.Absent_Date) = MONTH(E2.Absent_Date)  + 1

UNION ALL

SELECT  E2.Attendance _No,
        E2.Absent_Date
FROM Attendance  E1
JOIN Attendance  E2
ON E2.Attendance _No = E1.Attendance _No
AND MONTH(E2.Absent_Date)  = MONTH(E1.Absent_Date) + 1
JOIN Attendance  E3
ON E3.Attendance _No = E2.Attendance _No
AND MONTH(E3.Absent_Date) = MONTH(E2.Absent_Date)  + 1

UNION ALL

SELECT  E3.Attendance _No,
        E3.Absent_Date
FROM Attendance  E1
JOIN Attendance  E2
ON E2.Attendance _No = E1.Attendance _No
AND MONTH(E2.Absent_Date)  = MONTH(E1.Absent_Date) + 1
JOIN Attendance  E3
ON E3.Attendance _No = E2.Attendance _No
AND MONTH(E3.Absent_Date) = MONTH(E2.Absent_Date)  + 1

) A
```